# Making a calculator in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a calculator in matlab ... I made the window of the calculator but now I do not know how to take the inserted values and display the result in the textfield which I call `result` ...

```
prompt={'Enter your numbers:','Result:'};
title='Calculator'; 
% The main title of your input dialog interface.
answer=inputdlg(prompt,title);
numbers = str2num(answer{1}); 
Result = getvalue(numbers);
% Convert these values to a number using str2num.
```

when I type and add two numbers in `numbers = str2num(answer{1});` , I do not get its result in result field ... 
What I have to do to correct the code to make it works?
thanks

EDIT:

```
prompt1={'Enter your numbers:','Result:'};
prompt2={'Enter your numbers:','Result:'};
% The main title of your input dialog interface.
answer=inputdlg(prompt1);
numbers = str2num(answer{1}); 
svar=outputdlg(prompt2);
Result = str2num(get(numbers).svar{1});
% Convert these values to a number using str2num.
```

Comment: ```inputdlg```, the key is in the name, 'input' dialog. Not 'output' dialog.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here. What are you expecting the user to enter into the two fields?

Comment: you have to use `guide`. Type it and follow the related instructions in the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: @NKN There's no reason he _has_ to use GUIDE. This is poor advice.

Comment: please look at the EDIT ,, I wanted to use keyboard to input and add two numbers in first field which is `numbers = str2num(answer{1}); ` and then display the result in `Result = str2num(svar{1});` thanks

Comment: what is `outputdlg`? I think that what you're looking for is `msgbox` perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, but this might help:

```
number1_str = inputdlg('Enter the first number:');
number2_str = inputdlg('Enter the second number:');

number1 = str2num(number1_str{1});
number2 = str2num(number2_str{1});

msgbox(sprintf('The result of %i + %i is %i', number1, number2, number1 + number2))
```

**EDIT:** To input both numbers from the same dialog, try this:

```
numbers_str = inputdlg({'Enter the first number:', 'Enter the second number:'});

number1 = str2num(numbers_str{1});
number2 = str2num(numbers_str{2});

msgbox(sprintf('The result of %i + %i is %i', number1, number2, number1 + number2))
```

Comment: thanks .. If I want to have the two inputs in the same window , How do I do that?